# how install curl php in centos

Tags: php, curl, centos, php-curl, php-ini

i'm trying to install curl to my centos OS by yum
when I check

```
curl --version
```

it shows

```
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2 Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

but when I run `php -m` still doesn't gets curl lib.

Or

```
Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

I had change file **php.ini** by drop `;` at `extension=php_curl.dll` and restart service httpd but doesn't seems to  work. Can someone tell me

Answer (score 3):

According [this article](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-curl-php-linux/) you should to do next:

**Login as  root and run**

```
yum install curl
```

**Installing php-curl**

```
yum install php-curl
```

Answer (score 1):

Installed curl and php-curl, but not work? The reason may be:

The "curl.ini" file in /etc/php.d/ may be disabled (renamed to curl.ini.disabled).

Do the following:

```
ls /etc/php.d/
mv /etc/php.d/curl.ini.disabled /etc/php.d/curl.ini 
systemctl restart httpd.service
```